# When displaying a download rate to users should it be Mbps or MB/s?

Tags: download, uploading, speed, progress

If a program is displaying the speed of a download (or an upload), how should that speed be displayed to the user?  Mbps (Megabits per second) or MB/s (Megabytes per second) or something else?

It seems like people like to emphasize using Mbps for data rates yet browsers seem to measure download speed in KB/s or MB/s.

Answer (score 2):

MB/s.

That's the common way most people recognise download speed as.

I believe service providers use Mbps because that's the speed they can guarantee 'to your front door'. After that it's up to you what you actually get (in MB/s) based on a lot of factors like router, cables, Wi-Fi strength and range.